# Как рисовать графики с погрешностями в Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть массив данных и погрешность к обоим координатам. Как на графике отобразить это стандартным крестом?

Comment: Нужно что-то вроде [этого](http://www.inp.nsk.su/~grozin/python/python6.html#%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5), только по двум координатам?

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример данных

Answer (score 3):

Метод `errobar` может принимать ошибки по двум координатам: yerr и xerr для ошибок по оси y и по x соответственно.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 15)
y = np.random.random_sample(15)
xerr = np.random.random_sample(15) / 10
yerr = np.random.random_sample(15) / 10

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, fmt='o-', ecolor='red')
plt.show()
```